# Crear un subset de un archivo.txt a partir de otro archivo.txt CMD linux

Tags: linux, archivo, awk

Estoy trabajando en la consola de Linux, y tengo un archivo.txt(1) separado por tabulaciones con 4 columnas de 300 filas y otro . txt(2) con 6 columnas de más de 16000 filas.
Me gustaría comparar las primeras 4 columnas del primer archivo(1) con el segundo archivo(2), y en el caso de que coincidan esas 4 columnas, crear otro archivo.txt(3) extrayendo la información de las 6 columnas presentes en el archivo.txt(2). Básicamente es crear un subset. Lo he intentado con grep y awk, pero no lo consigo.
Muchas gracias :)

Comment: necesitaríamos un [mcve] para entender mejor el problema. Es decir, proporciona ejemplo de entrada, de salida y el código que has intentado hasta la fecha

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta que su archivo de 4 columnas tiene el nombre `f4.txt`:

```
a   b   c   d
e   f   g   h
x   x   x   y
```

y que el archivo de 6 columnas es `f6.txt`:

```
a   b   c   d   x   y
x   x   x   x   y   x
e   f   g   h   y   z
x   x   y   x   z   x
```

Con el programa awk `46.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS  = "\t"
    OFS = "\t"
}
FNR == NR {
    h[$0] = 1
    next
}
h[$1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4] == 1 {
    print
}
```

La ejecución se realiza de la siguiente manera (el orden de los archivos es muy importante):

```sh
awk -f 46.awk f4.txt f6.txt > r46.txt
```

Resultados:

```
a   b   c   d   x   y
e   f   g   h   y   z
```